# fputc and fgetc(in C) for values greater to 255?

Tags: c, file

What happens when I write (via `fputc`) a value bigger than 255 into a file?

Here is my code:

```
inputFile = fopen("arx.txt", "wr"); 
int a = 253;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("writing %d\n", a);
    fputc(a++, inputFile);
}
int b = 2 * 253;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("writing %d\n", b);
    fputc(b++, inputFile);
}
```

and that's what I see in the file

> **ύώ ϊϋόύώ**

I need to write these values to arrays instead of files and I must know what happens inside `fputc` and `fgetc`.

Any help?

Comment: Reading documentation helps. From [`man fputc`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fputc): *fputc() writes the character c, **cast to an unsigned char**, to stream.*

Comment: `"wr"` is not a standard mode string for `fopen()`.

Comment: Perhaps this could be of use to you: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/unicode.html When working with values > 255, you are outside of the range of an unsigned char. As such, you will need to work with values not as chars, but as some larger datatype such as shorts or ints. Of course, to do that you will have to avoid normal character processing functions because many of them will be incompatible with these larger values.

Answer (score 3):

The function `fputc` writes to the output stream the converted to the type `unsigned char` its argument.

Because the function returns the character it wrote you can easily check what character was written

Consider the following demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int c1 = 257;

    int c2 = fputc( c1, stdout );

    printf( "c2 =  %d\n", c2 );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
c2 =  1
```

Take into account that you specified incorrect function open mode `"wr"`. In this case the behavior is undefined. Just use `"w"`.

Comment: I find the Standard slightly ambiguous on this point. C11 §7.21.5.3 3 says that this is undefined behavior, but goes on to say in a footnote that: "If a string begins with one of the above sequences, the implementation might choose to ignore the remaining characters...." GCC seems to follow this path. Should we call this undefined behavior or implementation-defined behavior?

Comment: @DavidBowling  AFAIK footnotes are not normative.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. So it should be called UB, according to the Standard. But is GCC then failing to conform here? I must admit that I find these sorts of footnoted caveats a bit confusing.

Comment: @DavidBowling Sometimes compilers have their own language extensions as for example variable length arrays in C++ that contradict the Standard.

Comment: @DavidBowling: `gcc` has nothing to do with this, the behavior of `fopen()` is fully defined in the C library. You are referring to the Glibc, but be aware that many environments use `gcc` with a different runtime library.

Comment: @chqrlie I am referring the C Standard.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I was commenting David's comment: the handling of `"wr"` passed to `fopen()` is a C library issue, not a compiler issue.  Some compilers cannot easily be separated from their runtime, such as Visual C++, but `gcc` can interface to various C libraries. Phrases like *GCC seems to follow this path*, *But is GCC then failing to conform here* are irrelevant.

Comment: @chqrlie Where did I write that it is a compiler issue?! Did you read my post? I wrote that it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: **you did not**, David did! My comment was addressed to him. Starting a comment with an `@` followed by a member handle is a direct answer to a previous comment from that member.  Your answer is fine, with just one small caveat: the output starts with the terminal's interpretation of `\001` which might be visible or not.

Comment: @chqrlie-- Thanks for the comment; I appreciate the distinction. I do have an unfortunate habit of associating `glibc` with GCC. I will try to be more aware of this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`fputc()` writes bytes to its output stream. Its first argument, an `int`, is converted to `unsigned char` before writing to the file. On a system with 8-bit bytes, the file will contain this (hexadecimal dump):

```
00000000  fd fe ff 00 01 fa fb fc  fd fe                     ýþÿ..úûüýþ
```

How this contents displays on your system depends entirely on the tool and environment you use to *see it*.

You cannot output Unicode code points beyond the range of `unsigned char` to a file with `fputc()`, you must encode them in a way compatible with your system. You can use the generic UTF-8 encoding that is a widespread use today, or something more specific to your area.  You might be able to configure your locale and use the wide character input-output functions documented in the C Standard and defined in `<wchar.h>`: `fwide()`, `getwc()` and `putwc()`.